# Possible to change exchange 2003 ip address?

Tags: exchange-2003

Can an exchange server (2003) handle an ip address change? Without breaking the exchange install?

Comment: Which IP address are you talking about? The NIC on the server itself? The internet IP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is, "Yes, this is possible."  The reality is that if you didn't set up that mail server, and/or if anyone else has been in a position to change its configuration, it's likely that there are settings buried in that server which will cause glitches in this process.

E.g.  I managed an Exchange 2003 server with DNS hard-set in Exchange, even though the server (at the time) was using the same DNS settings via NIC config.  Took a while to ferret out the redundant setting throwing a monkey wrench into our network DNS change effort.

The moral of my ramble is that Exchange has a WIDE variety of opportunities to make a simple task explode into an overnight fiasco.  I would test your change in a virtual or sandbox setting ahead of time if it's even remotely possible.